# Recursive Prolog predicate for reverse / palindrome

Tags: list, prolog, reverse, palindrome, dcg

1. Can I get a recursive Prolog predicate having two arguments, called reverse, which returns the inverse of a list:

   Sample query and expected result:

   ```
   ?- reverse([a,b,c], L).
   L = [c,b,a].
   ```
2. A recursive Prolog predicate of two arguments  called `palindrome` which returns true if the given list is palindrome.

   Sample query with expected result:

   ```
   ?- palindrome([a,b,c]).
   false.

   ?- palindrome([b,a,c,a,b]).
   true.
   ```

Answer (score 7):

Ad 1: It is impossible to define `reverse/2` as a (<s>directly</s> edit thx to @repeat: tail) recursive predicate - unless you permit an auxiliary predicate.

Ad 2:

```
palindrome(X) :- reverse(X,X).
```

But the easiest way is to define such predicates with DCGs:

```
iseq([]) --> [].
iseq([E|Es]) --> iseq(Es), [E].

reverse(Xs, Ys) :-
   phrase(iseq(Xs), Ys).

palindrome(Xs) :-
   phrase(palindrome, Xs).

palindrome --> [].
palindrome --> [E].
palindrome --> [E], palindrome, [E].
```

Comment: Using DCGs is a nice solution here.

Answer (score 7):

There isn't an efficient way to define `reverse/2` with a single recursive definition without using some auxiliary predicate. However, if this is nevertheless permitted, a simple solution which doesn't rely on any built-ins like `append/3` (and should be applicable for most Prolog implementations) would be to use an *accumulator list*, as follows:

```
rev([],[]).
rev([X|Xs], R) :-
    rev_acc(Xs, [X], R).

rev_acc([], R, R).
rev_acc([X|Xs], Acc, R) :-
    rev_acc(Xs, [X|Acc], R).
```

`rev/2` is the reversal predicate which simply 'delegates' to (or, wraps) the accumulator-based version called `rev-acc/2`, which recursively adds elements of the input list into an accumulator in reverse order.

Running this:

```
?- rev([1,3,2,x,4],L).
L = [4, x, 2, 3, 1].
```

And indeed as @false has already pointed out (+1),

```
palindrome(X) :- rev(X,X).
```

Answer (score 4):

Just for curiosity here goes a recursive implementation of reverse/2 that does not use auxiliary predicates and still reverses the list. You might consider it cheating as it uses reverse/2 using lists and the structure -/2 as arguments.

```
reverse([], []):-!.
reverse([], R-R).
reverse(R-[], R):-!.
reverse(R-NR, R-NR).
reverse([Head|Tail], Reversed):-
  reverse(Tail, R-[Head|NR]),
  reverse(R-NR, Reversed).
```

Comment: Nice try, but incorrect. I gave you +1 anyway. `reverse(1-[], Ys).` should fail, but it succeeds with `Ys = 1.` Then, `reverse(Xs, Ys), Xs = [1].` should succeed but fails. So you are not cheating, but simply implementing another procedure. We agree not to call this a predicate - I presume.

Comment: @false. You're right!. This will only work with proper input lists.

Comment: `reverse(Xs, [1]).` Isn't that a proper input list? It succeeds with `Xs = [1]-[].`

Comment: Ok, you beat me ;) It works only one-way, assuming the first argument is a proper list and the second argument is either another list or an uninstantiated variable. Will remove the answer in some minutes ;)

Comment: Leave your answer! People often believe that similar things might work.

Answer (score 0):

```
conca([],L,L).
conca([X|L1],L2,[X|L3]):- conca(L1,L2,L3).
rev([],[]).
rev([X|Y],N):- rev(Y,N1),conca(N1,[X],N).
palindrome([X|Y]):- rev([X|Y],N),equal([X|Y],N).
equal([X],[X]).
equal([X|Y],[X|Z]):- equal(Y,Z).
```

Comment: -1. No lines between your badly-named predicates, `conca/3` is just a copy of `append/3` which is ISO, `palindrome/1` destructures the list for no gain whatsoever (except preventing empty lists from being palindromes for no reason), and `equal/2` is no improvement on `=/2` except that it is unnecessarily more limiting. "What's new isn't good and what's good isn't new."