# Is the `append` predicate tail-recursive?

Tags: prolog, logic-programming

A typical code example of list processing in Prolog is `append`:

```
append([], Ys, Ys).
append([X | Xs], Ys, [X | Zs]) :- append(Xs, Ys, Zs).
```

My question is whether this program is tail recursive or not.  I guess not from my experience in functional languages.  However, I find it more difficult to judge for Prolog programs.  It seems to we have to take unification into consideration.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096656/should-i-avoid-tail-recursion-in-prolog-and-in-general/14100435#14100435

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, your (and hence the Prolog "standard" version of) `append/3` is tail-recursive. You can see this easily because the final goal is a call to `append/3` itself. Notice that a typical implementation of `append` in functional languages is *not* tail recursive, because the final call is an operation equivalent to `cons` in Lisp, corresponding for example to:

```
lisp_append([], Ys, Ys).
lisp_append([X|Xs], Ys, Zs) :-
        lisp_append(Xs, Ys, Zs0),
        Zs = [X|Zs0].
```

Example query, yielding a *local* stack overflow because tail call optimization cannot be applied:

```
?- length(Ls, 10_000_000), lisp_append(Ls, [], _).
ERROR: Out of local stack
```

Whereas your natural Prolog version of `append/3` works:

```
?- length(Ls, 10_000_000), append(Ls, [], _).
Ls = [_G8, _G11, _G14, _G17, _G20, _G23, _G26, _G29, _G32|...].
```

Notice that more predicates are naturally tail recursive in Prolog than in functional languages, due to the power of unification which lets you pull the description of partial results before a tail call. +1 for a good question.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.  But I am afraid I did not fully get what you mean by "pull ...".  Would you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: For example, in `lisp_append/3` you can exchange the last two goals and obtain a tail recursive predicate. Going further, you can even pull the unification into the clause head, which is the most natural way to write this in Prolog, and which is what you wrote from the start. You cannot exchange the order of these calls in functional languages because they cannot reason over partially instantiated results like a list `[X|Zs0]`, where `Zs0` is not yet known. It is a rather irritating property of functional languages that such basic a function as `append` is *not* naturally tail recursive.

Answer (score -1):

No, your code is NOT tail-recursive. 
Tail-recursive means that at the bottom of the recursion you get the answer that you ask for at the beginning directly.

If you trace your code, for example`append([1,2,3],[a,b,c],Out)`, your get:

```
Call:append([1, 2, 3], [a, b, c], _G4702)
Call:append([2, 3], [a, b, c], _G4756)
Call:append([3], [a, b, c], _G4759)
Call:append([], [a, b, c], _G4762)
Exit:append([], [a, b, c], [a, b, c])
Exit:append([3], [a, b, c], [3, a, b, c])
Exit:append([2, 3], [a, b, c], [2, 3, a, b, c])
Exit:append([1, 2, 3], [a, b, c], [1, 2, 3, a, b, c])
```

The values of the variables(`_G4762,_G4759,_G4756`) are passed up to `_G4702`, and `_G4702` is the answer.

We may have a tail-recursive version of append:

```
ap_tail_r([H|T],B,Ac,Out):-
   ap_tail_r(T,B,[H|Ac],Out).

ap_tail_r([],B,[H|Ac],Out):-
   ap_tail_r([],[H|B],Ac,Out).

ap_tail_r([],Out,[],Out).
```

Let trace again `ap_tail_r([1,2,3],[a,b,c],[],Out)`:

```
Call:ap_tail_r([1, 2, 3], [a, b, c], [], _G4786)
Call:ap_tail_r([2, 3], [a, b, c], [1], _G4786)
Call:ap_tail_r([3], [a, b, c], [2, 1], _G4786)
Call:ap_tail_r([], [a, b, c], [3, 2, 1], _G4786)
Call:ap_tail_r([], [3, a, b, c], [2, 1], _G4786)
Call:ap_tail_r([], [2, 3, a, b, c], [1], _G4786)
Call:ap_tail_r([], [1, 2, 3, a, b, c], [], _G4786)
Exit:ap_tail_r([], [1, 2, 3, a, b, c], [], [1, 2, 3, a, b, c])
Exit:ap_tail_r([], [2, 3, a, b, c], [1], [1, 2, 3, a, b, c])
Exit:ap_tail_r([], [3, a, b, c], [2, 1], [1, 2, 3, a, b, c])
Exit:ap_tail_r([], [a, b, c], [3, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3, a, b, c])
Exit:ap_tail_r([3], [a, b, c], [2, 1], [1, 2, 3, a, b, c])
Exit:ap_tail_r([2, 3], [a, b, c], [1], [1, 2, 3, a, b, c])
Exit:ap_tail_r([1, 2, 3], [a, b, c], [], [1, 2, 3, a, b, c])
```

The only variable that we are keeping tract of is `_G4786`, which is the answer that we look for at the first place.

What exactly the tail-recursive code does is: a. reverse the first part, b. put the reversed first part to the second part head by head, c. when the reserved first part is empty, the updated second part is the appended result.

Comment: What?! Your answer is flawed. Look at above answer by @mat for details.