# Prolog compressing list

Tags: list, prolog

I have a strange problem that I do not know how to solve.

I have written a predicate that compresses lists by removing repeating items.
So if the input is `[a,a,a,a,b,c,c,a,a]`, output should be `[a,b,c,a]`. My first code worked, but the item order was wrong. So I add a `append/3` goal and it stopped working altogether.

Can't figure out why. I tried to trace and debug but don't know what is wrong.

Here is my code which works but gets the item order wrong:

```
p08([Z], X, [Z|X]).
p08([H1,H2|T], O, X) :-
    H1 \= H2,
    p08([H2|T], [H1|O], X).
p08([H1,H1|T], O, X) :-
    p08([H1|T], O, X).
```

Here's the newer version, but it does not work at all:

```
p08([Z], X, [Z|X]).
p08([H1,H2|T], O, X) :-
    H1 \= H2,
    append(H1, O, N),
    p08([H2|T], N, X).
p08([H1,H1|T], O, X) :-
    p08([H1|T], O, X).
```

Comment: I'd recommend to use `dif/2` in place of `(\=)/2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`H1` is not a list, that's why `append(H1, O, N)` fails.
And if you change `H1` to `[H1]` you actually get a solution identical to your first one. In order to really reverse the list in the accumulator you should change the order of the first two arguments: `append(O, [H1], N)`. Also, you should change the first rule with one that matches the empty list `p08([], X, X)` (without it, the goal `p08([], [], Out)` fails).

Now, to solve your problem, here is the simplest solution (which is already tail recursive, as @false stated in the comments to this answer, so there is no need for an accumulator)

```
p([], []).                    % Rule for empty list
p([Head, Head|Rest], Out):-   % Ignore the Head if it unifies with the 2nd element
    !,                        
    p([Head|Rest], Out).
p([Head|Tail], [Head|Out]):-  % otherwise, Head must be part of the second list
    p(Tail, Out).
```

and if you want one similar to yours (using an accumulator):

```
p08(List, Out):-p08(List, [], Out).

p08([], Acc, Acc).
p08([Head, Head|Rest], Acc, Out):-
    !,
    p08([Head|Rest], Acc, Out).
p08([Head|Tail], Acc, Out):-
    append(Acc, [Head], Acc2),
    p08(Tail, Acc2, Out).
```

Comment: Your first version is already tail recursive. It only makes the error for: p([a,Y],[a,b]). which should succeed.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected my statement. Author used unification and not equivalence in his original solution (and specified that list elements will be characters and not unbound variables).

Comment: @false, actually why is the first one tail recursive? There is a `cons` operation (`[Head|Out]`) that can be done only after satisfying the recursive goal.

Comment: The unification in the last clause with `[Head|Out]` is performed prior to the recursive call. Nothing is left (except the cons `[Head|Out]` but that needs to be produced anyway.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096656/should-i-avoid-tail-recursion-in-prolog-and-in-general/14100435#14100435

Comment: yes, `p/2` is tail-recursive save for the *cons* operation, but Prolog can perform the cons `[A|B]` *before* a logvar is instantiated by the recursive call. This is known as [tag:tailrecursion-modulo-cons].

Answer (score 2):

Pure and simple:

```
list_withoutAdjacentDuplicates([],[]).
list_withoutAdjacentDuplicates([X],[X]).
list_withoutAdjacentDuplicates([X,X|Xs],Ys) :-
   list_withoutAdjacentDuplicates([X|Xs],Ys).
list_withoutAdjacentDuplicates([X1,X2|Xs],[X1|Ys]) :-
   dif(X1,X2),
   list_withoutAdjacentDuplicates([X2|Xs],Ys).
```

Sample query:

```
?- list_withoutAdjacentDuplicates([a,a,a,a,b,c,c,a,a],Xs).
Xs = [a,b,c,a] ;         % succeeds, but leaves useless choicepoint(s) behind
false
```

---

#### Edit 2015-06-03

The following code is based on [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915) and [reified term equality](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13664870/4609915) [`(=)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29708684/4609915) by @false, which---in combination with first argument indexing---helps us avoid above creation of useless choicepoints.

```
list_without_adjacent_duplicates([],[]).
list_without_adjacent_duplicates([X|Xs],Ys) :-
   list_prev_wo_adj_dups(Xs,X,Ys).

list_prev_wo_adj_dups([],X,[X]).
list_prev_wo_adj_dups([X1|Xs],X0,Ys1) :-
   if_(X0 = X1, Ys1 = Ys0, Ys1 = [X0|Ys0]),
   list_prev_wo_adj_dups(Xs,X1,Ys0).
```

Let's see it in action!

```
?- list_without_adjacent_duplicates([a,a,a,a,b,c,c,a,a],Xs).
Xs = [a,b,c,a].          % succeeds deterministically
```

Answer (score 2):

In this answer we use [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate) `foldl/4` and
[Prolog lambdas](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord).

```
:- use_module(library(apply)).
:- use_module(library(lambda)).
```

We define the logically pure predicate`list_adj_dif/2` based on [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915) and [`(=)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915):

```
list_adj_dif([],[]).
list_adj_dif([X|Xs],Ys) :-
   foldl(\E^(E0-Es0)^(E-Es)^if_(E=E0,Es0=Es,Es0=[E0|Es]),Xs,X-Ys,E1-[E1]).
```

Let's run the query given by the OP!

```
?- list_adj_dif([a,a,a,a,b,c,c,a,a],Xs).
Xs = [a,b,c,a].                           % succeeds deterministically
```

How about a more general query? Do we get all solutions we expect?

```
?- list_adj_dif([A,B,C],Xs).
      A=B ,     B=C , Xs = [C]
;     A=B , dif(B,C), Xs = [B,C]
; dif(A,B),     B=C , Xs = [A,C]
; dif(A,B), dif(B,C), Xs = [A,B,C].
```

Yes, we do! So... **the bottom line** is?

Like many times before, the monotone if-then-else construct `if_/3` enables us to ...

- ..., preserve [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity), ...
- ..., prevent the creation of useless choicepoints (in many cases), ...
- ..., and remain monotone—lest we lose solutions in the name of efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

More easily:

```
compress([X],[X]).

compress([X,Y|Zs],Ls):-
       X = Y,
       compress([Y|Zs],Ls).

compress([X,Y|Zs],[X|Ls]):-
       X \= Y,
       compress([Y|Zs],Ls).
```

The code works recursevely and it goes deep to the base case, where the list include only one element, and then it comes up, if the found element is equal to the one on his right , such element is not added to the 'Ls' list (list of no duplicates ), otherwise it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
compr([X1,X1|L1],[X1|L2]) :-
   compr([X1|L1],[X1|L2]),
   !.
compr([X1|L1],[X1|L2]) :-
   compr(L1,L2).
compr([],[]).
```

Comment: Since you have a few lines of code here, could you please describe how this works and answers to question to make it easier for future visitors to understand your answer?