# addition of numbers, in a list, that are smaller than a given number

Tags: list, prolog, addition

i'm studying prolog and I have to creat a program that returns the addition of numbers (in a list), that are smaller than a given number.
I have this..

```
additionsmaller([X|XS],K,R):-X>K, additionsmaller(XS,K,R).
additionsmaller([X|XS],K,R):-X<K, additionsmaller(XS,K,T), R is T + X.
additionsmaller([X],K,X):-X<K.
additionsmaller([X],K,0):-K<X.
```

I expect for example:

```
additionsmaller([1,2,3,4,2],4,R).
R=8
```

But it give me false.

I'm using this https://swish.swi-prolog.org

What can I do to fix this? what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem cames from the fact that, for a value `V` you handle only the cases `X<V` and `X>V` not the case `X=V`. In fact, if you replace `X>K` with `X>=K`, your program will give the result `R=8`.

Let me say two things about your program:

First of all, you don't need the last two lines in your code (i.e. `additionsmaller([X],K,X):-X<K.`  and `additionsmaller([X],K,0):-K<X.`). Just replace these two lines with `additionsmaller([],_,0).`

Second: you should consider also to write a tail recursive solution, like this:

```
additionSmallerTail([],_,V,V).
additionSmallerTail([H|T],K,V,V0):-
    H >= K,
    additionSmallerTail(T,K,V,V0).
additionSmallerTail([H|T],K,V,V0):-
    H < K,
    V1 is V+H, 
    additionSmallerTail(T,K,V1,V0).

?- additionSmallerTail([1,2,3,4,2],4,0,R).
R = 8
false
```

Why using tail recursion? [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096656/should-i-avoid-tail-recursion-in-prolog-and-in-general) is interesting.