# What is predicate and differences lists in this?

Tags: ocaml

I am doing [OCaml 99](http://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/99problems.html), and can't quite understand some terms in this problem.

---

**A string representation of binary trees. (medium)**

[image]

Somebody represents binary trees as strings of the following type (see example): "a(b(d,e),c(,f(g,)))".

1. Write an OCaml function which generates this string representation, if the tree is given as usual (as `Empty` or `Node(x,l,r)` term).
2. Then write a function which does this inverse; i.e. given the string
   representation, construct the tree in the usual form.
3. Finally, `combine the two predicates in a single function
   tree_string` which can be used in both directions.
4. Write the same predicate tree_string using `difference lists` and a
   single predicate tree_dlist which does the conversion between a tree
   and a difference list in both directions.

For simplicity, suppose the information in the nodes is a single letter and there are no spaces in the string.

---

**Here are my questions:**

1. What does `predicate` mean in this problem?
2. For the 3rd point, it asks to make a function which can be used in both directions, i.e., can accept a tree and output a string or accept a string and output a tree. Should I use `functor` or something like that?
3. I totally can't understand the 4th point. What is `difference lists`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These problems were originally intended to be solved in Prolog, which explains the terminology I think.

In Prolog a predicate can represent an equality (or maybe isomorphism is a better word?) between two sorts of values, such that if you have a value of one sort it can actually calculate the value of the other sort. I.e., it works as a two-way function. It's not at all clear how to code this in OCaml. Maybe you should peek at the answers?

A difference list is a Prolog data structure. Here's a SO page that seems to explain them (I googled very quickly): [Understanding difference lists (Prolog)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20169862/understanding-difference-lists-prolog)

Comment: Do you think there is a difference list in OCaml? or does it make sense or is useful in OCaml?

Comment: could you please also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22020879/how-to-write-the-bnf-for-this-tree-related-operation?

Comment: I think you can have difference lists with Prolog's semantics using laziness (`lazy` in OCaml), but it is so tricky as not to be worth it.