# How to write the BNF for this tree-related operation?

Tags: syntax, bnf

We have a tree like this:

[image]

We can convert it to a `dotstring representation`, i.e.,

> Such a tree can be represented by the preorder sequence of its nodes
>   in which dots (.) are inserted where an empty subtree (nil) is
>   encountered during the tree traversal.

So we can convert the tree in the picture to `'abd..e..c.fg...'`.

If I am about to write a function to do this conversion, what's the `BNF` or `syntax diagrams` of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you're asking. If you think of the string as a sentence in a language and the tree as an AST for a parse, maybe the following BNF would be right:

```
tree ::= empty | node
empty ::= '.'
node ::= letter tree tree
letter ::= 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' | 'f' | 'g' | ...
```