# How do I write a palindrome program while using different lists?

Tags: list, prolog, palindrome, dcg, difference-lists

I tried to write a palindrome program by using lists. However, I have to use **difference lists** and output should be:

> The i<sup>th</sup> element of the list is the same of
> (n-i+1)<sup>th</sup> element of the list and n is the length of the
> list. For example, `[a,X,c,b,Y]` should give `X = b` and `Y = a`.

So far I have implemented:

```
% length of the list 
len([], 0).
len([H|T], B) :-
   len(T, NT),
   B is NT + 1.

% return the ith element of the list 
match([H|_], 0, H) :-
   !.
match([_|T], N, H) :-
   N > 0,
   N1 is N-1,
   match(T, N1, H).
```

How do I complete this?

Comment: Prolog already has `length/2`, so you don't need to write your own list length predicate (`len/2`). There's also a Prolog predicate to return the n-th element of a list, (see SWI Prolog's `nth0/3` or `nth1/3`). Also, what you're describing is a *palindrome*. You can probably find several examples to work from by searching for, "prolog palindrome".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding difference lists (Prolog)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20169862/understanding-difference-lists-prolog)

Comment: @mescalinum i dont think so. I also searched other questions  about palindrome. Could you please help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Use definite clause grammars!**

DCG, a *major Prolog feature*, makes using difference lists easy—enabling you to write concise *and* efficient code with little effort!

*Want to know more?* Just follow the dots:

- DCG has its own tag on StackOverflow, [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg).
- [en.wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org) has an extensive [article on DCG](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_clause_grammar).
- For a jumpstart, read the [DCG primer by Markus Triska](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/dcg.html)!

Without any further ado, let's get to the code:

```
palindrome --> [].
palindrome --> [_].
palindrome --> [X], palindrome, [X].

% Alternatively, we could also use the following more compact definition:
palindrome --> [] | [_] | [X], palindrome, [X].
```

**Done.** Let's run a few queries! First, the query the OP gave:

```
?- phrase(palindrome, [a,X,c,b,Y]).
   X = b, Y = a
;  false.
```

In German, "corn" is called ["mais"](http://www.dict.cc/?s=mais). If we put ["siam"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siam_(disambiguation)) (the old name of "the Kingdom of Thailand") in front, we get a *delicious* palindrome:

```
?- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).
true.

?- phrase(palindrome, "siammais").
   true
;  false.

?- phrase(palindrome, "siamais").       % or kick one middle 'm' character
   true                                 % ... for an odd-length palindrome
;  false.
```

At last, let's not forget about the *most general query*:

```
?- phrase(palindrome, Xs).
   Xs = []
;  Xs = [_A]
;  Xs = [_A,_A]
;  Xs = [_A,_B,_A]
;  Xs = [_A,_B,_B,_A]
;  Xs = [_A,_B,_C,_B,_A]
...
```

---

On the [prolog-toplevel](/questions/tagged/prolog-toplevel) we can use the built-in Prolog predicate `listing/1` to peek at the code the DCG was "translated" to—at this level the internal use of [difference-lists](/questions/tagged/difference-lists) becomes apparent:

```
?- listing(palindrome//0).
palindrome(A, A).
palindrome([_|A], A).
palindrome([C|A], D) :-
    palindrome(A, B),
    B = [C|D].

true.
```